# JDK Hotspot C1 compiler is enabled and C2 is disabled by default in Java Azure functions

Tags: java, jvm, azure-functions

Azure functions [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-java?tabs=bash%2Cconsumption#customize-jvm) suggests hotspot compiler C1 is enabled and, C2 is disabled by default in azure functions. What could be reason behind this? I would like to enable both C1 and C2 to take advantage of hotspot compiler optimizations but want to know if it causes any problem in azure functions and due to that this default behavior was added.

Following are options given in documentation:

```
-XX:+TieredCompilation (To enable C1)
-XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1 (To disable C2)
```

Comment: Hotspot compilation is only helpful when the same JVM will be running the same code for an extended period.

Comment: Are you saying azure function is going to spin up new JVM on each invocation?

Comment: `-TieredCompilation` disables C1. But here is `+TieredCompilation`.

Comment: Well, C2 takes time to produce optimized code, and consumes lots of CPU resources. For short-lived processes or in the environments with limited CPU resources, C2 just does not pay off (or even degrades application start-up time). Other than that, nothing stops you from turning on C2 in Azure functions - you may try yourself and choose the configuration which performs better.

Answer (score 1):

`-XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1` actually enables only `C1` compiler (by disabling `C2`). The reason for that is faster start-up times, but hurts later optimizations obviously.

The same pattern is taken by `Spring` with their spring-boot plugin and `bootRun`, btw.

Another reason is that they could have measured the time and seen that since those functions are run only once, `C2` might not be *that* beneficial, but this is only a a guess.

Comment: Any reference can you provide of these parameters in Spring?

Comment: @Vipin [for maven mojo for example](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-tools/spring-boot-maven-plugin/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/maven/RunMojo.java#L77)

Comment: I think this answer is what we can guess from jvm point of view. I am looking for more concrete reason why azure function is using this. If I don’t get my answer I will try to dig in myself and provide concrete reason.